Metric of Normal Bundle
If I had a circle bundle over some base manifold $\mathcal M$, I could write the line element in local coordinates as
$$ds^2=g_{ij} dx^i dx^j+\phi(x)(dz^2+A_i dx^i)^2,$$
where $g_{ij}$ is a Riemannian metric for the base space $\mathcal M$, $z$ is the circle coordinate, and $A_i$ is the local form of the connection. I'm wondering if one can do something similar for a normal bundle. Suppose I have a codimension-one submanifold of a Riemannian manifold, with a normal vector $n=n^i\partial_i$. For a non-trivial normal bundle, is it necessarily true that the metric can be expressed as
$$ds^2=h_{ij}dx^i dx^j+\phi(x)(n_i dx^i+A_i dx^i)^2,$$
where $h_{ij}$ is the induced metric on the submanifold?

What is the connection doing as part of the metric?

I (perhaps naively) assumed that the "normal bundle connection" would appear in the same way the usual fiber bundle connection appears in the metric

You’re not answering my question. Why are you using a connection in the metric in the first place? In any event, the circle bundle comes from a rank-2 bundle, and so there is no immediate analog. The normal bundle is likely a trivial bundle.

A circle bundle is a U(1) principal bundle, so it is natural for the U(1) connection to appear. Perhaps I've been exposed to too much theoretical physics, but the above form of the circle bundle metric is the standard Kaluza-Klein form. I was just wondering if something similar applied to normal bundles. Obviously, for a trivial normal bundle, no connection is necessary, but I was wondering about the case specifically of a non-trivial normal bundle. I know one can write various metrics (Sasaki, Cheeger-Gromoll, etc) but none of them are quite in the same form as above
